# Android - Get keys in nested object Firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Using Firestore in Android, is it possible to read the keys in the nested object "items" below?

```
{
    "email":"someemail@someaddress.com",
    "items": {
      "8G9RiMgx9SmDLYrQbNrN": true,
      "K19RiMr7SmDLYrQbNrN": true
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added and answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a [Firestore `DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot) representing that JSON structure, you can get the keys of the items with:

```
DocumentSnapshot document = ...

Map<String, Object> items = (Map<String, Object>) document.get("items");
Set<String> keys = items.keySet();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Try this code, it :

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject("youJson");
data = data.optJSONObject("items");
Iterator<String> iter = data.keys();

//Iterate all the keys
while (iter.hasNext()) { 
    String key = iter.next();
    Boolean value = json.optBoolean(key); //Get the actual value 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by iterating over a `map` like this:

```
yourRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                Map<String, Object> items = (Map<String, Object>) document.get("items");
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : items.entrySet()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi gareoke! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?